# Socket-io 400 Failures

Tags: flask, socket.io

I'm using "socket.io-client" in my React Native app and receiving data from a websocket hosted in my flask app using flask_socketio. But when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk I'm getting intermittent 400 errors. I'm not quite sure what's going on, does anyone know?

> OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor Apr 28 00:02:40 ip-172-31-7-208
> web: [2023-04-28 00:02:40 +0000] [4238] [ERROR] Socket error
> processing request. Apr 28 00:02:40 ip-172-31-7-208 web: Traceback
> (most recent call last): Apr 28 00:02:40 ip-172-31-7-208 web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py",
> line 271, in handle Apr 28 00:02:40 ip-172-31-7-208 web: keepalive =
> self.handle_request(req, conn) Apr 28 00:02:40 ip-172-31-7-208 web:
> sock.sendall(data) Apr 28 00:02:40 ip-172-31-7-208 web: OSError:
> [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor